# When compare two version of a specific component, got error message:(80040356) Array cannot be null. Parameter name: bytes Array cannot be null

Tags: web8

When tried to compare two version of a component in Tridion Web 8, it always popup an annoying error message:
(80040356) Array cannot be null. Parameter name: bytes Array cannot be null. Parameter name: bytes

But it's working well when perform the same thing upon a template in Web8.
And working also in Tridion 2011.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: What's Web 9? Are you from the future??

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the CM server? Can you also post the trace from console of developer tools or firebug when performing the compare? That would help isolating the issue.

Comment: Can you raise ticket with SDL team , may be they will provide hotfix for above issue.